# Exit order when price is lower than entry bar low

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to set my stop-loss at the low of my entry bar.

what is the condition I need to use ?

I try

```
if strategy.position_size < 0
    strategy.exit(id="Close Short", stop=low[1])
```

but this my stop-loss change everytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are recalculating `low` on each bar where `strategy.position_size < 0`.

You want to calculate `low` only after you've entered the position. Try:

```
if ta.change(strategy.position_size) 
    strategy.exit(id = "Close Short", stop = low)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are updating your exit order on each bar you are in a trade with `low[1]`. What you want to have is a constant SL price.

Store your SL target when you enter a trade in a `var` variable. Then use it in your exit call.

```
is_new_pos = (strategy.position_size[1] == 0 and strategy.position_size != 0) or ((strategy.position_size[1] * strategy.position_size) < 0)

var float sl_price = na
sl_price := is_new_pos ? low[1] : sl_price // If it is a new position update the SL price, else keep the old value

if strategy.position_size < 0
    strategy.exit(id="Close Short", stop=sl_price)
```

Comment: What I should put in "na" ?

Comment: Leave it `na´. It will update it's value when you enter a trade.